# Heroku Play framework 2 sbt dependencies cache

Tags: java, heroku, dependencies, playframework-2.0, sbt

I managed to add some dependencies (via the sbt dependency manager in play framework) that seem to be in conflict with other libraries I use. However when i removed them from the sbt dependency manager and run play clean compile.

It seems like something is still there in the dependency cache.

Im not entirely sure which library that messes things up so i then tried emptying the repository folder (inside the play core folder where all dependencies are put with sbt)

I then run play clean compile again. And now everything works.

I would like to do the same thing in my production environment on heroku.

Im thinking i could try as suggested in this thread

[How to clean Heroku dependency cache (unmanaged maven dependencies)

To use this buildback https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java.git#cache_clear

But does anyone know if it totally rebuilds the dependencies and deletes the old ones? Since i dont know what the buildpack does, you think it would be safe? Could it break my application somehow?

Thans for any help.

Kr,

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning your build cache is safe. It will wipe all dependencies and do a fresh build. It sounds like this would clear up your problem. If the cache clearing fails for some reason it won't make a release to your app so there's no risk to your running application.

However since this is a Play 2 app it uses the Scala buildpack (Yes, even if your app is Java. Play 2 is written in Scala. Confusing, I know). There's a cache clearing branch of that buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala.git#cleancache

If you run into other questions and want to learn more about Java and Scala builds on Heroku this article is an excellent start: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/debugging-java-scala-builds